# import aws_cdk core results in TypeError across interfaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a CDK project initialized with:

```
cdk init --language python
```

I activate the .env with (windows 10)

```
call ./.env/scripts/activate
```

I have Anaconda flavored Python 3.6

I install deps...

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

At this point, all `cdk`-related commands result in the same error:

```
C:\...\.env\lib\site-packages\aws_cdk\core\__init__.py", line 1554, in <module>
    class DependableTrait(metaclass=jsii.JSIIAbstractClass, jsii_type="@aws-cdk/core.DependableTrait"):
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'jsii_type'
```

I can get this from:

```
cdk ls

# or
cdk diff

# or
python -c "from aws_cdk import core"
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by moving from Anaconda flavored Python to Python 3.7

Once I did this all the steps listed above worked for me.